# Installing a smart thermostat with strange HVAC wiring

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to wire up my smart thermostat for a C-Wire Adapter. I have a C wire going to the water heater I think (I can't really see where the wire is leading up to)

There is a free blue wire I can use for the C connection to thermostat, so the C-Wire Adapter might be unnecessary.

The thermostat has the red wire going to C, and the a small jumper cable from C to R.

[image]

Additional Images: https://imgur.com/a/6vQC0Ei

Any help is appreciated so I can install the smart thermostat.

Comment: What is this "Safe T Switch" that the cable on the right leads to? Also, do you have central air conditioning?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have a Central Air Conditioning.

I looked up what Safe-T-Switch does, apparently it detects clogged A/C Condensate drains and shuts off the system to prevent water damage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Connect the blue wire from the thermostat cable to C

Your wiring isn't so strange after all, it turns out, despite the seeming oddness with the condensate float switch spliced into the R wire to the thermostat (which I don't like, as it can cause smart thermostats to lose their mind should it trip).  You see, your outdoor unit needs to be told when to run by the thermostat, so it gets passed Y (to send the signal) and C (to complete the circuit) from the indoor system, hence the cable going off to the left in your diagram.  (It's going off to the outdoor compressor unit for your air conditioning, *not* your water heater.)